# how can I get the return status code when using iframe.src to download a file?

Tags: javascript, iframe, http-status-codes

Here is the `downloadURL` function which I'm using to download a file:

```
function downloadURL(url) {
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
    iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;
};
```

This can work perfectly for downloading a file, but right now, I want to **get the return http status code**, if the http status code is not 200, I'd like to `alert` something out.

Could anyone tell me how to retrieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can get the status code from an iframe.  You can try adding an `onload` event to the iframe.  The event object might have some useful info.

Comment: Could you give me some specific thing like code snippet? I'm new to javascript and I hope you can prove what you say :） Thanks bro~@RocketHazmat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955947/how-do-i-get-the-http-status-code-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible. You can try with ajax as it is shown here:
[Use javascript to check http status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571227/use-javascript-to-check-http-status-codes)