# Jquery if statement not working even if the statement is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple if statement where when i send this certain data to the database, i want the php code to send bake a code that tells javascript its ok to continue, but if the php script sends back a bad code, javascript is to now move forward and display a certain text or something.

The php code works fine but for some reason my javascript files would not work at all.

My javascript is suppose to ajax request to parse.php and receive the data that parse.php sends back to it, if parse.php says 200 its suppose to load in specific items.

Here is the code for one of my systems:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chatForm").submit(function(){
        var chatHash = $("#chatHash").val();
        var body = $("#chatPoster").val();
        var by = $("#userBy").val();

        if(chatHash != "" && body != ""){
            $.post('parse.php',{chatHash: chatHash, body: body, userBy: by},function(data){
                if(data == "200"){ // Right here is where its messing up
                    $("#chatPoster").val("");
                    $.get('getChatMessages.php?hash=' + chatHash,function(data2){
                        $(".allMsgs").html(data2);
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Critical error');
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the code for the parse.php page:

```
$chat = new ChatSystem;
if(isset($_POST['chatHash']) && isset($_POST['body']) && isset($_POST['userBy'])){
    $chat->sendMessage($_POST['userBy'],$_POST['chatHash'],$_POST['body']);
}
```

Here is the code from the class ChatSystem that the parse.php page is referring to:

```
    public function sendMessage($user,$hash,$body){
    global $db;

    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $time = date("H:i:s");

    $timestamp = "$date $time";
    if(empty($user) == false && empty($hash) == false){
        $db->query("INSERT INTO chat_messages VALUES('','$user','$body','$timestamp','','0','$hash')") or die("error");
        echo '200'; 
    }
}
```

Even though my php code works perfectly the javascript still messes up. My php code sends back 200 like i ask it to but yet the jquery messes it up

Comment: Why do you think, that `data` should have value `"200"` ? What is *actually* there? `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: I think you are trying to check the response status 200... are you

Comment: Try console.log(data) and post what you have

Comment: `alert(data)` to see if the value is `200` or an array or something else...

Comment: `data` will be whatever `parse.php` printed. It's not the HTTP status code.

Comment: @ArunPJohny ive put up the full code for the system what the 200 means is that the php file has succeed in sending the message to the database!

Comment: Just to amuse us, add `alert(data)` to your before `if`.

Comment: You should sanitize the $_POST data before insertting to database. YOu have vulnerability to SQL Injections.

Comment: @JoniSalmi Well dont worry about that one i have a special little function that will protect my site from sql injection

Comment: Try this `if(data.trim() == "200"){ `

Comment: @Barmar lo li  already did and it says that my php code sent back 200

Comment: @JoniSalmi nope it still isnt working properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955947/how-do-i-get-the-http-status-code-with-jquery

Comment: @Kamlesh He's not trying to get the status code, his PHP contains `echo 200`.

Comment: What about `data.substring(0,3) == "200"`

Comment: Just to be clear, since you never said it in the question. It's alerting `Critical error`?

Comment: yes it is @Barmar its suppose to alert critical error when the php returns something other than "200"

Comment: Make sure you have nothing before `<?php` or after `?>` in the file.

Comment: @Barmar yeah i did check that! But it has to be something wrong with the javascript because the php code is absolutely fine. Its also doing this to my other javascript files that has the same logic as this one!

Comment: Javascript doesn't get such a basic operation wrong. There must be an invisible character somewhere. `alert(data.length)`.

Comment: ok now javascript is ignoring the line of code above and is just outputting critical error @Barmar

Comment: Which do you think is more likely, that Javascript arbitrarily skips statements in your program, or that you've entered it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints using the Javascript debugger, so you can examine the data instead of wasting time with alerts? Do you even know how to use the debugger?

Comment: not really, how do i use it? Maybe that would help @Barmar

Comment: I don't have the time to walk you through that. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: Just for giggles, put this just above the failing line: `data = data.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` and see if that helps.

Comment: ok lemme see if it works @JeremyMiller

Comment: OK, but that's *not* the answer... it's a patch.  Your PHP isn't returning just 200, it's returning some extra crap on the left or right of the 200 and my patch is just stripping away everything that's not a number.  Look for the extra code.  Also, upvote people who help you. ;)

Comment: Ok ima find the extra stuff its returning tommorow and for sure ima upvote you @JeremyMiller

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look here, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/.
You need a second parameter to the success callback function to be able to catch the response status code.
I.E. `function(data,statusCode){ // check the status code here}`

Comment: He outputs the 200 himself. It's not about that

Comment: @JoniSalmi right i even said output works and it still didnt work. Like 2 hours ago it was working perfectly, now it does not!