# Handle AJAX redirection for not authorized AJAX HTML requests MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a MVC 5 application and loading partial views through AJAX. The problem I am facing is when the session expires or the user is not authenticated anymore. From what I have searched, there was a [way to detect the 401 code in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12626979/2004799) and handle the redirection, tried it and it works. I wanted to make a wrapping function to handle all these cases, since I make a lot of AJAX calls to get HTML or JSON, but the redirect to the login page is not working:

```
<meta name="loginUrl" content="'@Url.Action("Authenticate", "Account", new { Area = "" },Request.Url.Scheme)'"/>
//<meta name="loginUrl" content="'@Url.Action("Authenticate", "Account", new { Area = "" }'"/>

 function AuthorizedAJAX(url, method, data, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        statusCode: {
            200: success,
            401: function (d) {
                console.log($("meta[name='loginUrl']").attr("content"));
                //window.location.href=$("meta[name='loginUrl']").attr("content");
                window.location.replace($("meta[name='loginUrl']").attr("content"));
                return false;
            },
            500: error
        }
    });
}
```

What happens is that the login view, with the full HTML is loaded in the div. I know I am missing something small but can't figure this out.