# CFML How to get status code from an ajax response

Tags: ajax, header, response, http-status-codes, cfml

I am almost done making a web app with CFML but I have a question on handling errors. For example, a part of my web app can execute user entered SQL code. However if the SQL code the user provides isn't valid then it will not execute properly and I get an error like this:
https://devintranet.dep.gov/oogns/sharedComponents.cfc 500

Which makes sense. If it helps answering my question at all here is the information on the network tab:
[image]

All I want is to be able to catch when the status code returns 500 and be able to take action based on that. For example if I make a request that ends up having a status code of 500 then I can use JS alert to tell the user something went wrong.

Here is the function in sharedComponents.cfc:

```
<cffunction name="LoadAttribute" access="remote" returnformat="plain" returntype="string" >
    <cftry>

    <cfquery name ="AttributeQuery" datasource="RBDMS_UPDATE">
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.OOGNS_Queries
        WHERE UPPER(QueryName) = UPPER(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#form.default_ProfileName#" />)
    </cfquery>

    <cfcatch>
      <cfoutput>
        #cfcatch.Detail#<br />
        #cfcatch.Message#<br />
        #cfcatch.tagcontext[1].line#:#cfcatch.tagcontext[1].template#
      </cfoutput> 
    </cfcatch>
      </cftry>

      <cfreturn AttributeQuery["#default_ColName#"][1] /> 

      </cffunction>
```

And here is the ajax function that calls it:

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
            url: "sharedComponents.cfc",
            data: { method: "LoadAttribute",
                    default_ProfileName: ProfileName,
                    default_Entity: Entity,
                    default_ColName: ColName,
                  },
            datatype: "json"
    }).done(function(returnresult) {
```

There is actually a lot of code after that but I believe it to be irrelavent to what I'm trying to do. Literally if you can show me how to obtain the status code from the response header I think I'll be good.

Comment: This is not exactly cfml related, because you are asking how to detect http status code response with your ajax jquery call. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955947/how-do-i-get-the-http-status-code-with-jquery however, you can catch cfml errors by  using cftry/cfcatch and change your components response to whatever you want to and adapt your jquery ajax function to react accordingly.

Comment: Read the [jQuery AJAX implementation doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it has error handling built in. You just need to use the settings. _HINT:_ see the **error** section.

Comment: @AndreasRu Sorry I had a family emergency and have been away from home for over a week and I just say this but you're comment helped me get where I needed. I got it working. Thank you a ton.

Comment: @ColePerry can't send you a private message through stackoverflow, so I'm posting this as a comment. Glad I could help somehow and I hope very much you and your family and your beloved ones are all fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues in your request.

1. Catch errors on server side

   It can be that the requested column is not available in the `AttributeQuery` result. So you have to check for that before accessing it.

   One way to do this is:

```
<cfreturn structKeyExists(AttributeQuery, default_ColName) ?
    AttributeQuery[default_ColName] : "" />
```

2. Catch errors on client side

   To catch HTTP errors you can [use the `error()` function jQuery's `ajax()` function provides](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), as Miguel-F and AndreasRu mention in their comments.